# Different coverage when pytest is run on a single module

Tags: python, testing, pytest, test-coverage

I am using pytest to test my code. When I test the module `matreader.py` I obtain a 100% coverage:

```
(jade) C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests>pytest matreader_test.py
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests
collected 9 items

matreader_test.py .........                                                                                      [100%]

================================================== warnings summary ===================================================
matreader_test.py::TestMatCardList::test_translation
  C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests\..\libmanager.py:186: UserWarning:  The Deafult library 81c was used for zaid 1001
    warnings.warn(MSG_DEFLIB.format(self.defaultlib, zaid))

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
============================================ 9 passed, 1 warning in 1.12s =============================================
```

but if I test the entire folder containing more modules, the coverage for `matreader.py` drops to 50%:

```
(jade) C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests>pytest
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests
collected 32 items

inputfile_test.py ...                                                                                            [  9%]
libmanager_test.py ....                                                                                          [ 21%]
matreader_test.py .........                                                                                      [ 50%]
output_test.py .                                                                                                 [ 53%]
parsersD1S_test.py .............                                                                                 [ 93%]
sphereoutput_test.py ..                                                                                          [100%]

================================================== warnings summary ===================================================
matreader_test.py::TestMatCardList::test_translation
  C:\Users\d.laghi\Documents\GitHub\JADE\Code\tests\..\libmanager.py:186: UserWarning:  The Deafult library 81c was used for zaid 1001
    warnings.warn(MSG_DEFLIB.format(self.defaultlib, zaid))

-- Docs: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/warnings.html
============================================ 32 passed, 1 warning in 3.38s ============================================
```

I tried to have a look to the pytest doc but I couldn't find the explanation for this behaviour.

Comment: It's impossible to say for sure what's wrong without a [mcve]. Usually, however, this is caused by early importing modules, before `coverage` starts actually tracking them. Try checking when `matreader` is first imported in both runs and deduce why that happens.

Comment: Actually I got it now, the percentage shown by pytest has nothing to do with coverage. Is simply to be intended as a progress bar indicating how many tests have been run so far against the number of tests that have been collected